# Fast Walsh-Hadamard Transform in Rust

Tags: rust, parallel-processing

I'm having a hard time to get a Rust code to compute the Walsh-Hadamard transform efficiently inplace. The algorithm is by essence highly parallelizable but it requires two nested for loops.
This is easy in C, see below the code using OpenMP which is fast.

```
void FWHT32(int32_t* array, int n){
    uint32_t d, i, j;
    for(d=n; d > 0; d--){
        uint32_t D = ((uint32_t)1<<d);
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
        for(j=0; j < ((uint32_t) 1 << (n-d)); j++){
            for(i=0; i < (D >> 1); i++){
                array[D*j+i] = array[D*j+i] + array[D*j+(D>>1)+i];
                array[D*j+(D>>1)+i] = array[D*j+i] - 2*array[D*j+(D>>1)+i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in Rust I get a really hard time iterating in parallel over two distant values, my best attempt so far doesn't parallelize the inner loop:

```
use std::ops::{AddAssign, Sub};
use rayon::prelude::*;

pub fn _par_fast_walsh_hadamard_tr<T: Send + Copy + Sized + AddAssign + Sub<Output = T>>(array: &mut [T]) {
    let arlen = array.len();
    let n = arlen.trailing_zeros() as usize;
    if arlen != (1 << n) {
        panic!("Length must be a factor of 2.");
    }

    for step in 0..n {
        let s = 1 << (n - step);
        array.par_chunks_exact_mut(s)
            .for_each(|chunk| {
                for j in 0..s/2{
                    let a = chunk[j];
                    chunk[j] += chunk[j+s/2];
                    chunk[j+s/2] = a - chunk[j+s/2];
                }
            });
    }
}
```

But even this runs only slightly faster on 6 cores / 12 threads compared to a trivial sequential Rust implementation.
Is Rayon not the right parallel framework for this?

How can one parallelize the inner loop?

Comment: I see a similar result on my machine (an old intel mac) on a 128MB array, without `par_` in the algorithm I get 3.7s wall clock, and 3.4s user time. With `par_` I get 3.5s wall clock, and 13s user time..  my guess is that the for the small length chunks the overhead is too high.

Comment: How do you measure? Using [criterion](https://crates.io/crates/criterion) and [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67eaf6bc350ae4aea09b645e0f57db8b), I get 1.6ms for the single-thread and 5.1ms for the parallel version on a 6-core machine.

Comment: Sorry I meant 1.6ms for the **parallel** version and 5.1ms for the single-thread.

Comment: When I look step by step I see that the sequential version has kind of the same profile: it is slow in the few rounds with large chunks and then fast. Could it be that Rust is doing some parallel optimization?

Comment: I am testing with std::time::Instant and cargo build --release executable. But if I take @Jmb code but with larger array (0 .. 1_024*1_024*32) I also get comparable time (parallel 226.6ms _vs_ single 237.0ms) which is counter-intuitive: the parallelization should be best with large data to process.

Comment: `std::time::Instant` is very bad at measuring small durations, much better to use a dedicated benchmark framework.

Comment: Note that for large data sets (when the data no longer fits in the cache), you will start hitting memory bandwidth limitations, which can't be improved by multi-threading (and may in fact be worsened as different threads try to pull different parts of the data into the cache).

Comment: I see, maybe the data retrieval time starts to dominate especially when the computations are very light. I still wonder how can we parallelized the inner loop as it may allow the threads to better manage data retrieval.